# Vertify an equivalent condition for feasible circulation

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization

A circulation in a directed graph $D$ is a function $g:E(D)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the conservation condition at every vertex. Let $l,u:E(D)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}_{0}$ be a lower and upper capacity function, resp. And assume for each edge $e$, $l(e)\le u(e)$.

A circulation $g$ is feasible if $l^(e)\le g(e) \le u^(e)$ for every edge $e$.

Prove that there exists a feasible circulation iff $l^+(A)\le u^-(A)$ for every set $A\subset V(D)$.

There is a hint: Add a vertex $s$ and an edge from $s$ to every vertex of $D$, and a vertex $t$ and an edge from every vertex of $D$ to $t$. Define $c(sv)=l^-(v), c(vt)=l^+(v), c(e)=u(e)-l(e)$ for $v \in V(D)$ and $e \in E(D)$. Given a flow f of value $\Sigma_{e\in E(D)} l(e)$ in the network thus defined, consider $f+l$.

I proved the forward direction. In the backward direction, I can't show that whether $f$ exists and whether $f+l$ is a circulation.

Comment: Can you confirm that $l^+$ and $u^-$ are defined for vertices, that they represent sums over outgoing and incoming edges, and there's a typo in your definition of feasible?

Comment: Thank you! I revised the typo. And $l^+$ and $u^-$ are defined for vertices that they represent sums over outgoing and incoming edges.